# Lost my phone in Termini Station, Rome

Tags: lost-luggage

My brother lost his phone in/near the Termini Station on Sunday, November 20th - 16:00 to 16:50.

The phone's model is a one plus 3, with it being gold color at the back.

Can you please check if one has been reported found? Likely place to have dropped the phone would be near the trenitalia ticket purchased at 16:32, which was at the immediate left of the entrance to the termini station (where the buses to the airport depart).

Phone has precious memories in them. I'm hoping it wasn't pick pocketed, and instead just lost. :-(

Comment: Has your brother tried to [locate the phone with Android Device Manager](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491?hl=en)?

Comment: I think it's extremely unlikely that the phone was "just lost", unfortunately.

Comment: @dan1111 I lost various phones on Italian's railways a few times, and even one on the Dubai metro -I've got the habit to remove them from the pocket and put it on a seat near me, before sitting down- and I always got them back easily. But I notice something like a phone is missing at max a couple of minutes after coming down the train, not 4 days later :-D

Comment: We are an internet question and answer site. We are not the Italian railway company, the Italian police, or any other organization who might be able to find your phone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not the lost property office.

Answer (score 8):

We're a travel website and are not responsible for Termini Station.

The people responsible for the station recommend that you contact the [lost property office](http://www.romatermini.com/en/service/detail/lost-property) run by the Rome City Council and/or the Railway Police.

The telephone number listed on that page is 06 67693214 / 3217.

Comment: I'd upvote twice, if I could.